# Populate data on column based on Dropdown list

Tags: excel, excel-2010

i have two to tables.

Table A:

[image]

Column H..needs to get populated with data from another column(Table 2 - Column I) based on what i choose on my Dropdown List on Table A.

Table B:

[image]

So far i couldn't make it work..it will only populate the first cell (H6)

my code so far

```
=INDEX(datasource_tranquility_order_type_buy_page_19[Jita-Prices],ROWS($1:50), MATCH('Delve-Market'!H3,datasource_tranquility_order_type_buy_page_19[[#Headers],[Jita-Prices]],0))
```

Comment: How are the values in the second column structured, i.e. do you have a column or row named Jita Prices?

Comment: Only huge column with no name..and around 10.000 integer values.

Comment: How do you want to match with no identifier ?  i.e. how should table 1 be populated based on the drop-down?

Comment: Jita-Prices it's just a generic name. For example, my dropdown list on this case says Jita-List...if "Jita List" is chosen on Dropdown list, then populate the following column on table 2 to Table 1 Column, if else populate this other list, else none.Hope that pseudocode was clear.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to offer this in the format of an Answer because it isn't one. It's an invitation to modify your question.

1. Get rid of snake names like `datasource_tranquility_order_type_buy_page_19`.
2. You need to have a list of items for your primary validation drop-down. Give this list a one-word name. Make sure it exists in your workbook. It doesn't matter where but if it's in columns I or H please point that out. Add the name to your question (Edit the question).
3. Where is your drop-down? Add this info to your question.
4. Create a named list for each item in the primary drop-down. Say you have ="List19,List20,List21,[etc]" in the primary drop-down you must have lists by these same names in your workbook. (After we're done here you can replace the short names with snakes again lol:)
5. Now, if you select "List20" in the drop-down, column H can be populated with the values contained in your list of that name.

Last, but by no means least, for the above idea to be realized you will probably need code. If you do expect code you will have to show some own effort. If you expect a solution using worksheet functions your own effort will be adequate. Maybe some other members here will be willing to work with your endless names even though I wouldn't. But let me say that achieving the result with worksheet functions is a lot more difficult, at least for me. Either way, please, when you amend your question, also specify your expectation in this regard.

I shall delete this "Answer" as soon as you have acknowledged its content.